# What is the most efficient way to do multiple or comparisons if some are conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a value, `val` which I want to check if it is one of several values (`1`, `2`, or `3`).  Normally the way I would do this is:

```
if val in [1,2,3]:
```

However, I only want to include `3` if another condition is met (`test`).  Ungracefully put, it would be this:

```
if val in [1,2,3] and (test if val == 3 else True):
```

This is a pretty awkward comparison (isn't very readable) and I'm testing if `val == 3` twice, so is there a way to do it all in one go? (i.e. more efficiently)  Thanks in advance,

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something that is more clear, not necessarily more efficient.  Am I reading your question correctly?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, a little of both, but more efficient is preferable than more readable since questions asking about more readable code can get pretty opinionated.  I want to avoid testing the condition twice or multiple conditions if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if val in [1,2] or (val == 3 and test):
   # do it
```

More efficient than with `and` and clearer. With `or` operator expression divided into 2 parts and right part evaluated only if left is `False`. From [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Comment: +1 for the logic rework. On the right side, `(test and val == 3)` might be a tiny bit more efficient, since you may get to skip the comparison operation.